# Значення слова "платянки"

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

Зустрів таке речення:

> "Він був міняйло і їздив однокінкою по селах, промінюючи голки,
>   дзеркальця, шила та всяку господарську подріб за **платянки**" (Іван
>   Франко).

Зацікавило слово "платянки", однак в СУМі його немає. Також вирішив пошукати в [Словничку галицизмів](http://blog.i.ua/community/3065/968726/), однак там теж його не знайшов. Можливо, хтось знає в якому значенні це слово вживається в даному контексті?

А також цікавить етимологія даного слова, бо пошуки в [Етимологічному словнику](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=436) також не дали ніяких результатів.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ВТССУМ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/946395.html)**

> ***Платянка*** -и, ж. , зах. Онуча.
>
> ***[Онуча](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53406/929178.html)*** 1. Шматок тканини, яким обмотують ноги перед взуванням (перев. в чоботи). 2. розм. Шматок старої, брудної тканини;
>   ганчірка.

[Російсько-український словник (Українська академія наук)](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53406/164286.html)

> ОНУЧА (-чі), (ум. онучка, онучечка), *платянка* (гал.) (ум. платяночка).

[Етимологічний словник](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=436)

ст.432

> Пла́ття, платтьови́й, платтяний, платя́ни́ця, ***пла́тя́нка*** – див
>   **плат.**

Повертаємося до ст.430, слово **"плат"**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Судячи з контексту - "він" збирав ганчір'я для подальшого продажу на фабрику, що виробляє папір (промисел, розповсюджений на початку 20 століття). На Вікіпедії немає української статті, ось англійська - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rag-and-bone_man

Answer (score 1):

*Часткова відповідь*:

У [Словнику української мови за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) знаходжу:

> **Платянка**, ки, ж. ***Портянка, онуча***. Ум. Платяночка. На білені платяночки ти красно обуйся. Гол. IV. 488.

Таку ж інформацію знайшла і [тут](http://www.geum.ru/next/art-30822.leaf-33.php):

> **Платянки** – онучі; ганчір’я.

Для детальнішого пояснення, берімо [CУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/onucha):

> **ОНУ́ЧА**, і, жін.
>
> 1. Шматок тканини, яким обмотують ноги перед взуванням (перев. в чоботи).
> 2. розм. Шматок старої, брудної тканини; ганчірка.

Отже, платянки - це шматки тканини, які використовують при взуванні.

Щодо етимології, на жаль, нічого не знайшла.